# How to do cookie-based authentication by using libcurl REST API?

Tags: libcurl

My web server supports cookie-based authentication. But I am not able to understand  how to implement it using libcurl REST API. i went thru the example https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cookie_interface.html as well. but I am confuse how to utilize this example for authentication. Every time I am getting " HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" error

code :

```
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, 
        "https://samplepage.com/LicenseReportingApplication/authenticate");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ""); /* start cookie engine */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_ALL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "root:admin123");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

below is the error log

```
C:\Windows\System32>C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\lib_curl\lib_curl_test\x64\Debug\lib_curl_test.exe
*   Trying 10.63.12.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to samplewebpage.com (10.63.12.112) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: disabled server certificate revocation checks
* schannel: verifyhost setting prevents Schannel from comparing the supplied target name with the subject names in server certificates.
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 169 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 169 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 872
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 872 length 4096
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 326 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 59
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 59 length 4096
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
* Server auth using Basic with user 'root'
> POST /LicenseReportingApplication/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: samplewebpage.com
Authorization: Basic cm9vdDphZG1pbjEyMw==
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

* schannel: client wants to read 16384 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 17408
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
* schannel: encrypted data got 293
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 293 length 17408
* schannel: decrypted data length: 263
* schannel: decrypted data added: 263
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 263 length 16384
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 263 length 16384
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 263
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 16384
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2019 03:58:51 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9AD72025C7716CA14346A6F9B7E1F49C; Path=/LicenseReportingApplication; Secure; HttpOnly
< Location: /LicenseReportingApplication
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443
* schannel: clear security context handle
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://samplewebpage.com/LicenseReportingApplication'
* Switch from POST to GET
* Hostname samplewebpage.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.63.12.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to samplewebpage.com (10.63.12.112) port 443 (#1)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: re-using existing credential handle
* schannel: incremented credential handle refcount = 2
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 169 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 169 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 872
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 872 length 4096
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 326 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 59
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 59 length 4096
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with samplewebpage.com port 443 (step 3/3)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'root'
> GET /LicenseReportingApplication HTTP/1.1
Host: samplewebpage.com
Authorization: Basic cm9vdDphZG1pbjEyMw==
Accept: */*

* schannel: client wants to read 16384 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 17408
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
* schannel: encrypted data got 165
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 165 length 17408
* schannel: decrypted data length: 135
* schannel: decrypted data added: 135
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 135 length 16384
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 135 length 16384
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 135
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 16384
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2019 03:58:53 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Location: /LicenseReportingApplication/
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #1 to host samplewebpage.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://samplewebpage.com/LicenseReportingApplication/'
* Found bundle for host samplewebpage.com: 0x475d90 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#1) with host samplewebpage.com
* Connected to samplewebpage.com (10.63.12.112) port 443 (#1)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'root'
> GET /LicenseReportingApplication/ HTTP/1.1
Host: samplewebpage.com
Authorization: Basic cm9vdDphZG1pbjEyMw==
Accept: */*

* schannel: client wants to read 16384 bytes
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
* schannel: encrypted data got 2816
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 2816 length 17408
* schannel: decrypted data length: 287
* schannel: decrypted data added: 287
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 287 length 16384
* schannel: encrypted data length: 2491
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 2491 length 17408
* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 287
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 16384
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2019 03:58:54 GMT
< Server: Apache
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8EAF9C77B57FD187DD660ACF66692851; Path=/LicenseReportingApplication; Secure; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 4447
<
* schannel: client wants to read 4447 bytes
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 2491 length 17408
* schannel: encrypted data got 1994
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4485 length 17408
* schannel: decrypted data length: 4447
* schannel: decrypted data added: 4447
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 4447 length 16384
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 4447 length 16384
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 4447
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 16384
```

Comment: I do not know for sure if this is related to your problem, but why do you use method "POST" without sending post data? Can you try with "GET" and see, if that works?

Answer (score 0):

The `401 Unauthorized` response means that your `Authorization:` header was deemed incorrect or not enough by the server. Failing to issue the right cookie won't cause a 401.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, const char* args[])
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {


        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sampleurl.com/LicenseReportingApplication/authenticate");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ""); /* start cookie engine */


        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=root&password=urpass");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_ANY);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_ALL);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: error %d %s\n", res,
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```